# a program made in c runs on double click in windows but not in linux

Tags: terminal, executable, gui

I have made a simple addition program in C in both OS, Linux (Ubuntu and CentOS) and Windows 7 with the same source code, which is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
int a,s,d;

printf("type the values u want to add and give tab between them\n");

scanf("%d %d",&a,&s);

d=a+s;

printf("addition is %d",d);

return 0;

system("read -p 'Press Enter to EXIT...' var");
}
```

In Windows it runs when I double-click on `addition.exe` but in Ubuntu (also in CentOS) when I click on the executable file `addition`, nothing happens. It does not run or open a terminal. However, it runs when I type `./addition` in a terminal.

But I want to run it by double-clicking on it.  What should I do?

The properties of that files are in this image:

[image: Properties of the "addition" executable file]

Also there is no option like "open in terminal" in the open with section of properties.

I also tried creating `.desktop` file which is as follows:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=addition
Type=Application
Exec=/media/smit/D/smits programs of c/projects by code blocks/02U/addition/bin/Debug/addition
Terminal=true
```

When I click on `addition.desktop` then it says an error occur while launching application.

I also tried to open it by copying this desktop file to `/usr/share/applications`.

Comment: OK, I think I've refined my answer up to everything that I could find about your code and tried to nail all the core issues. Let me know if you have any other questions

Comment: It _probably_ doesn't have anything to do with the issue, but please put a terminating newline in that `.desktop` file. And please also copy-paste the contents of that terminal screenshot

Comment: @Fox  nope, terminating newline doesn't affect `.desktop` file, at least in my tests

Comment: To narrow the problem, please try `Exec=/bin/sh -c '/path/to/your/app'`. This will start a shell to execute the program. The shell call should succeed and output what's wrong with the application call. And if the path contains spaces, you can surround it with double quotes inside the single quotes of the `-c` option. Paths with spaces are generally not helpful while debugging problems like this.

Comment: After reading the Answers below, I must agree that removing spaces in the path would help this issue tremendously.  What's wrong with `/home/smit/smitsCPrograms/codeBlocks`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The core of the issue is that you're trying to run the program, which is console application, but **you don't have terminal attached to it**. In terminal you can run your program by just calling the program name, but in GUI you need to specify explicitly that there should be a terminal window raised to run console apps (this is particularly true of GNOME-based desktops, such as Ubuntu's Unity).

What should be done is that you also need to create a `.desktop` file for your program with 4 fields. Here's an example:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=MyProg
Type=Application
Exec=/home/xieerqi/example_directory/hello_world_prog
Terminal=true
```

I don't know about CentOS, but as far as Ubuntu goes, it's the requirement that `.desktop` applications must be made executable also *if they are located in any directory under user's home directory*. `.desktop` files that live in other directories, such as `/usr/share/applications` do not require that.

So, once you have the `.desktop` file in place, and made it executable, you will be able to run the program. The important bit is `Terminal=true` line. That's what will tell GUI to raise a terminal and run your program there. **NOTE**: if your program executes stuff and exits immediately, you will need to have some sort of delay or `getchar();`  call just to keep the window open, because terminal window will exit when program exits. That's why many users are sometimes confused "Why is my program not running?" It runs, in reality, it just exits too fast.

---

**Additional notes**:

- get rid of `system("read -p 'Press Enter to EXIT...' var");` . The `read` call is a shell built in, and is **not a standalone program**, which means it only can be used if you use a shell, such as `bash`. If you are using C, do it properly using `scanf()` or `getchar()` to add delay to your program. It is present after `return 0;` line which means your `system()` line won't be reached (the program will just quit at `return` statement), so your placement of the pause for the program is also invalid.
- Read [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/90347/295286) on AskUbuntu for example of proper `.desktop` file with links to [official documentation](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/).
- If you are feeling lazy and don't want to make `.desktop` files for each and every executable file, there's plenty of solutions [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/64222/295286). I even posted a script there as well.

Comment: please look at my question cause i edited it.

Comment: OK, so you said you made the `.desktop` file and it shows the error. What are the contents of the `.desktop` file ? What error does it say ?

Comment: the content is in image.i cant open is so use cat command. and error is"There was an error launching the application" when click on addition.desktop file i can t add image due to my low reputation.

Comment: also tried this link "https://askubuntu.com/questions/64222/how-can-i-create-launchers-on-my-desktop" but it says "Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged"and desktop file made gives same error"there was an error launching the application"

Comment: @SmitPatil  I see, the issue is that you have spaces there. Replace your Exec like like this: `Exec=/media/smit/D/smits\ programs\ of\ c/projects\ by\ code\ blocks/02U/addition/bin/Debug/addition`.  The `Gtk` warning can be ignored - that's nothing we as users can fix - `zenity` developers have to fix that.  I'll edit my other answer to include automatic addition of forward-slash to spaces as well

Comment: still it saying "There was an error launching the application "

Comment: @SmitPatil I can't see any other issue there. Very strange.  Just a question:  you have compiled the program, right ? you're not trying to run just plain .c file , are you ?

Comment: yes i have compile program and it run fine in terminal by comand ./addition. i appreciate you effort to help me but i didn't find the answer yet.

Comment: Temporarily place the script in a directory that does not have special characters (e.g. space) in the path, and adjust the `.desktop` file accordingly. This is to see if the space character causes the problem. As I vaguely recall, I think spaces have to be denoted by `\s` in `.desktop` files.

Comment: @egmont  Before suggesting my previous comment, I've tested the `.desktop` file by altering executable name by adding spaces to it and changing `.desktop` file to add `\` to each space. I've never heard of `\s` being necessary and `\` works. But a good suggestion nontheless - OP should try moving executable to different path.